# How does the internal resistance of oscilloscope compare to that of the DMM?

Tags: resistance, oscilloscope, impedance, multimeter

Both are the instruments that measure voltage, so what are the difference between multimeter and oscilloscope in terms of their internal resistance ?

Comment: A hammer and a screwdriver are both tools to build furniture, so what is the difference between them in terms of size?

Comment: Set aside the way this question is formulated, oscilloscopes tend to have standard input resistances such as 1M in order to be compatible with as many probes as possible that allow a 10:1 attenuation. DMMs usually have as high an input resistance as possible, given their overvoltage protection, which is usually around 10M.

Comment: Question can be answered by referring to the specifications. Should be closed.

Comment: That would depend on your specific instruments, so just read the fine manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oscilloscopes tend to have standard input resistances such as 1M in order to be compatible with as many probes as possible that allow a 10:1 attenuation (little switch on the probe). DMMs usually have as high an input resistance as possible, given their overvoltage protection, which manufacturers usually set around 10M (but can be much higher for high-end devices).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the scope and the multimeter. Read the datasheet of the tool in question.

In general most multimeters are 10 Mohms and Oscilloscopes are 1 Mohm BUT when used through a 10:1 probe it will also be 10 Mohms.

Comment: Depends how old your multimeter is. 20kilohms/volt FSD was normal at one time. But then digital multimeters came along, and that changed :-)

Comment: True, I was assuming a digital meter. I still have a 50 kohms/V analog meter though :-) And a digital one that does 100 Mohms below 200 mV.

Comment: And while we're at it, the really cheap multimeters were 1000 ohms/volt.